# Webpack duplicating stylelint warning messages

Tags: webpack, sass, postcss, stylelint

Currently I am building my project with scss and I am trying to incorporate linting as I develop. I am using:
- Postcss (and postcss reporter)
- Extract text webpack plugin
- Stylelint

However, the warning messages from stylelint are duplicating. Here is my config

**Webpack Config**

```
{
  test: /\.scss$/,
  loaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      {loader: 'css-loader', options: {sourceMap: true}},
      {loader: 'postcss-loader', options: {sourceMap: true}},
      {loader: 'sass-loader', options: {sourceMap: true}}
    ]
  })
}
```

**Postcss Config**

```
const plugins = [
  require('stylelint'),
  require("postcss-cssnext"),
  require('css-mqpacker'),
  require("postcss-reporter")({ clearReportedMessages: true })
];
```

Something interesting if I put `require('stylelint')` right before `postcss-reporter` I get multiple stylelint messages.

Comment: when you say the messages are duplicating, can you give an example of how they are duplicating? What version of webpack are you on?